# Complicated url django

Tags: python, django, url

I would like to create a url like this:

example.com/reviews/state/city/school/program

The state, city, school and program have to be dynamically generated from the model. I have been Googling but I don't know the right question to ask. I am at an impasse. Until I sort this out, I don't really know how to write any views or the urls.py

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I have reviewed the tutorial on writing urls. However, I do not want to use numbers in my regexes. I would like for the URLs to be dynamically generated from the model fields. How do I do that?

App Models

```
from django.db import models

import numpy as np

class State(models.Model):
    short_name = models.CharField('State abbreviation', max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField('State Name', max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
    name = models.CharField('City', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'City'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cities'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ZipCode(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    zip_code = models.ForeignKey(ZipCode, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.street

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Address'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Addresses'

class Program(models.Model):
    program_type = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.program_type

class Specialty(models.Model):
    specialty = models.CharField('Specialty', max_length=30, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.specialty

class School(models.Model):
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, default='')
    specialty = models.ForeignKey(Specialty, default='', null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, default='')
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField('Date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'School'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Schools'
```

Comment: Well I'm afraid without asking a question we can't give an answer. Dynamic URLs are fundamental to Django and are well covered in the tutorial; the only extra thing is that you want to have several dynamic elements in your URL, but that just means several regex groups in your pattern. Where, specifically, are you having trouble?

Comment: Read the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/) on writing URLs.

Comment: I don't know what in the URLs documentation would lead you to believe it only works with numbers. If you want to use strings, then use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you can try creating a url like below in urls.py

```
urls.py
# dont forget import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^reviews/(?P<state>[a-z]+)/(?P<city>[a-z]+)/(?P<school>[a-z]+)/(?P<program>[a-z]+)/$',
        views.reviews, name='reviews')
]
```

your views.py should be something like this:

```
view.py
def reviews(request, state=None, city=None, school=None, program=None):
    # do something
```